# Merge lists in a dictionary that have a common element

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, merge

I would like to merge both keys and values of a dictionary if the values (lists) that share at least one element.

The input would be :

```
dico = {"a" : [1,2,3], "b":[9,2,89], "c":[3,12,530],"d":[34,42],"e":[34,6]}
```

And I would like the out to be something like this :

```
{"a,b,c" : [1,2,3,9,89,12,530], "d,e": [34,42,6] }
```

None of what I tried worked... Do you think this is possible?

Comment: You should post what you tried.

Comment: You should try [union find/disjoint set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) algorithm.

Comment: Should duplicates be removed from the joined lists? Is order in the joined lists important?

Comment: on which bases you combined like {"a,b,c" : [1,2,3,9,89,12,530], "d,e": [34,42,6] }???????
>> instead of {"a,b,c,d,e" : [1,2,3,9,89,12,530,34,42,6] }!!

Comment: @DexJ: He stated `share at least one element`. So `a` shares the number `2` with `b` and `a` shares the number `3` with `c` but `d` only shares `34` with `e`

Comment: @Jacobr365 : I started with : 
    def fusion (dico):
    dic = {}
    reste = list(dico.keys())
    for u in dico.keys():
        for v in dico.keys():
            if u!=v and (not set(dico[u]).isdisjoint(dico[v])==True):
                dic[u+";"+v] = list(set(dico[u]+dico[v]))
    return dic

But it keeps elements.. I wanted to remove objects little by little but I failed..

Comment: What to do when it is in multiple lists? :)

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k Ill try that

Comment: thanks @SierraMountainTech got it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use a [Union-Find aka Disjoin Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) approach. First, you need two functions: `union` and `find`. I usually keep those lying around somewhere in case I need them.

```
def find(x):
    l = leaders[x]
    if l is not None:
        l = find(l)
        leaders[x] = l
        return l
    return x

def union(x, y):
    lx, ly = find(x), find(y)
    if lx != ly:
        leaders[lx] = ly
```

Now, you can use those to determine one "leader" for each element in the lists...

```
dico = {"a" : [1,2,3], "b":[9,2,89], "c":[3,12,530],"d":[34,42],"e":[34,6]}
leaders = collections.defaultdict(lambda: None)

for val in dico.values():
    for other in val[1:]:
        union(val[0], other)
```

... and then group elements that have the same "leader" into groups.

```
groups = collections.defaultdict(set)
for x in leaders:
    groups[find(x)].add(x)
```

Now, also group the keys by the leaders of their first elements:

```
keys = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key in dico:
    keys[find(dico[key][0])].append(key)
```

And finally assemble the result.

```
result = {','.join(ks): groups[leader] for (leader, ks) in keys.items()}
# {'d,e': {42, 34, 6}, 'c,a,b': {1, 2, 3, 9, 12, 530, 89}}
```

Note that this is using sets, though, instead of lists. If you need to retain the original order, just group the keys and then chair their respective lists together.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! @tobias_k